# Where to Store NopCommerce Custom Theme/Views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I'm new to ModX and have Experirnce with MVC3. I have a PSD that im coding into HTML and CSS. When I open the NopCommerce solution in Visual Studio, I see the themese folder. Is that where my custom theme assets should be saved?

After building the solution, do I need to run the prepare and deploy batches and copy deploy folder contents in order for changes to take effect?

Finally, where in the source code do I change Manufacturers to Restaurants?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Themes go in Nop.Web.Themes.  Create a folder there named after your theme and include your Content and Views folders.  You should also have a theme.config XML file in your folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Theme title="YOURNAME" 
       supportRTL="false"
       previewImageUrl="~/Themes/YOURNAME/preview.png"
       previewText="YOURDESCRIPTION">
</Theme>
```

If your site is already running, you should be able to just move your Theme folder to it for changes to take effect.